# Risk of using a third-party nameserver

Tags: networking, domain

I registered a domain from a company, and hosting my website in DigitalOcean. DigitalOcean offers a nameserver service, in which I have to point to DigitalOcean nameserver from my registrar. This is the instruction to do so, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-point-to-digitalocean-nameservers-from-common-domain-registrars. From what I see, there is no procedure to ensure the owner of the domain is using it on DigitalOcean. I wonder if it is possible, someone, who knows I point my current nameserver to DigitalOcean nameserver and register the domain before I do, can actually point the domain to an ip address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but then you just contact Digital Ocean customer support and resolve the issue.